# Can a numerically indexed php array be created from enumerated HTML INPUT values without assigning one-by-one?

Tags: php, html

Looking for a faster way to create a numerically indexed PHP array from similarly named HTML input values than assigning each individually:

HTML

```
<input type = "text" name = "input1" value ="first value">
<input type = "text" name = "input2" value ="second value">
<input type = "text" name = "input3" value = "third value">
<input type = "text" name = "unrelated" value = "some other value">
```

can these values be easily extracted (from among $_REQUEST values) into a php array to produce this?

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  string(11) "first value"
  [2]=>
  string(12) "second value"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "third value"
}
```

note - the PHP array indexes are integers, not strings from the input names.

Comment: WHY!!!!! They are in an array. Well 2 actually, The $_REQUEST array and the $_POST array

Comment: Just do a `var_dump($_REQUEST);` and look at it

Comment: I don't understand. why don't you just copy your $_REQUEST into another array?
`$myForm = $_REQUEST`

Comment: I dont know why people are afraid of $_POST/$_GET. Once PHP builds it from the form data passed to it. ITS ALL YOURS. You can do what you like with it, add to it, remove from it. Whatever you like

Comment: clarifying that the array indexes are integers only for the enumerated inputs.  Not the input names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way: rename your `<input>` `name`s to `input[]`.

```
<input type = "text" name = "input[]" value ="first value">
<input type = "text" name = "input[]" value ="second value">
<input type = "text" name = "input[]" value = "third value">
<input type = "text" name = "unrelated" value = "some other value">
```

```
var_dump($_REQUEST['input']);
```

Although that would always result in zero-based sequential integer index.

However, if you have no control over the HTML code, or must always maintain the index:

```
function tooLazyToName(array $arr, $name)
{
    $new = [];
    $len = strlen($name);

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $baseName = substr($key, 0, $len);
        $index = substr($key, $len);

        if (!$index || !ctype_digit($index)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (strncmp($baseName, $name) === 0) {
            $new[(int)$index] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $new;
}

$arr = tooLazyToName($_REQUEST, 'input');
var_dump($arr);
```